# ByteBuffer.wrap().getInt() equivalent in c#

Tags: java, c#, memorystream, bytebuffer, binarywriter

**Java**

```
byte[] input = new byte[] { 83, 77, 45, 71, 57, 51, 53, 70 };

int buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).getInt();
```

Output: `1397566791`

**C#**

```
byte [] array = { 83, 77, 45, 71, 57, 51, 53, 70 };

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
     writer.Write(array);
}
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

int buff = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Output: `1194151251`

I have no idea how to get the *same* output

Thanks

Comment: `int buff = BitConverter.ToInt32(array.Take(4).Reverse().ToArray());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Int32` consists of `4` bytes only, let's `Take` them with the help of `Take(4)`. Next, we have to take *ending* (Big or Little) into account and `Reverse` these `4` bytes if necessary:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  byte[] array = { 83, 77, 45, 71, 57, 51, 53, 70 };
        
  // 1397566791
  int buff = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
    ? array.Take(4).Reverse().ToArray()
    : array.Take(4).ToArray());
```

Comment: Unlike my thought, some may think the problem encountered is too easy. However, I'm captivated by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Java case, it's taking the first 4 bytes in order and converting them to an int.

```
System.out.println((((((83<<8)+77)<<8)+45)<<8)+71);
1397566791
```

In C# it is taking the first four in reverse order.

```
System.out.println((((((71<<8)+45)<<8)+77)<<8)+83);
1194151251
```

So you need to read the API documentation that describes the operation for both classes and use them accordingly.  There should be a way to reverse the byte order.

To go from C# to Java it would be something like this.

```
buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
System.out.println(buff);
```

Prints

```
1194151251
```

Comment: I like the shifting.